# Push or Merge data into existing Array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, array-push

When working with existing code, it takes one array and places it into another in the fashion shown below.

I believe the empty brackets are the same thing as simply pushing it and appending it to the first available index.

```
$g['DATA'][] = $p;
```

After this is done, I have my own array that I would like to append to this as well. I tried using `array_merge()` with `$g['DATA'][]`as a parameter, but this is invalid for obvious reasons.

My only thought is to create a `foreach` loop counter so I can figure out the actual index it created, however I have to assume there is some cleaner way to do this?

Comment: So after you added an array (here `$p`) you want to merge your own array with it in `$g["DATA"][UNKNOWN]`, right?

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I am wondering how to accomplish without a counter variable on the foreach loop its contained inside of.

Comment: `$g['DATA'][count($g["DATA"])-1] = array_merge($g['DATA'][count($g["DATA"])-1], $ownArray);` <- Something like this or do you want to merge your array with ALL subArrays from `$g["DATA"]` ?

Comment: Ah that first example is what I needed, so simple and completely over thinking that. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Should I convert it into an answer?

Comment: Yes please do, I think someone else may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use the [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) of your `$g["DATA"]` array as index and then you can merge it like this:

```
$g['DATA'][count($g["DATA"])-1] = array_merge($g['DATA'][count($g["DATA"])-1], $ownArray);
         //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         // -1 Because an array is based index 0 -> means count() - 1 = last key
```